# xml highlighting in sublime2 text editor

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext2

Is there a plugin to get xml tag highlighting in sublime2 text editor as in notepad++?

In notepad++ as soon as i click on a tag, the ending tag is highlighted. I like this feature, specially for very large xml files. I am including examples below of the same part of the files which i opened in sublime text and notepad++.

example in notepad++:
[image]

example in sublime2:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) plugin should do what you want. I know he is almost ready to roll out version 2 of the plugin (the BH2 branch of the github page in the link). It is in package control though, for easy installing. If you have questions about it, the developer has been pretty good at answering questions, so you can try posting on the [Sublime Text Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3327) as well.

Comment: installed BracketHighlighter plugin from package control, but the feature is not there yet i guess

Comment: @iceman Really? It didn't do something like this for you ([link](http://i.imgur.com/X75Nh.png))? I know you can't see it, but the cursor is on "path". Perhaps an error occurred in yours? You might want to try checking the console, and then reporting a bug if there is one.